# How to count and summarize rows in two or more separate tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

as following, I have two tables in SQL like below:

Request Table:

```
+------------+------------+--------+
| #technician| #RequestID | #title |
+------------+------------+--------+
| emma james | 1121       | title10|
+------------+------------+--------+
| emma james | 2155       | title11|
+------------+------------+--------+
| emma james | 8787       | title12|
+------------+------------+--------+
| john roody | 9584       | title13|
+------------+------------+--------+
| john roody | 8744       | title14|
+------------+------------+--------+
| scott olga | 1556       | title15|
+------------+------------+--------+
| tom jonas  | 9941       | title16|
+------------+------------+--------+
```

Task Table:

```
+-------------+---------+---------+
| #owner      | #taskID | #title  |
+-------------+---------+---------+
| emma james  | 232     | title0  |
+-------------+---------+---------+
| emma james  | 945     | title1  |
+-------------+---------+---------+
| tom jonas   | 542     | title2  |
+-------------+---------+---------+
| tom jonas   | 887     | title3  |
+-------------+---------+---------+
| tom jonas   | 215     | title4  |
+-------------+---------+---------+
| john roody  | 268     | title5  |
+-------------+---------+---------+
| scott olga  | 258     | title6  |
+-------------+---------+---------+
```

how can we summarize the count of Appearance for each technician name in a separate table by Query like this:

```
+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
| #Name      | #RequestIDcount | #TaskIDcount | #TotalCount |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
| emma james | 3               | 2            | 5           |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
| tom jonas  | 1               | 3            | 4           |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
| john roody | 2               | 1            | 3           |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
| scott olga | 1               | 1            | 2           |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Using `COUNT`? What have *you* tried? Why didn't it work. [so] isn't a free coding service, so please don't treat it like one. Have a read of the [tour], as you are yet to.

Answer (score 0):

One method is `union all` and aggregation:

```
select name,
       sum(is_request) as num_requests, sum(is_task) as num_tasks,
       (sum(is_request) + sum(is_task)) as total
from ((select technician as name, 1 as is_request, 0 as is_task
       from requests
      ) union all
      (select owner, 0, 1
       from tasks
      ) 
     ) rt
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, here's one using `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT
  ISNULL(r.name, t.name)                    AS name,
  ISNULL(r.num_r, 0)                        AS num_requests,
  ISNULL(t.num_t, 0)                        AS num_tasks,
  ISNULL(r.num_r, 0) + ISNULL(t.num_t, 0)   AS total
FROM
  (SELECT technician AS name, COUNT(*) AS num_r FROM requests GROUP BY 1) AS r
FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT owner      AS name, COUNT(*) AS num_t FROM tasks    GROUP BY 1) AS t
    ON r.name = t.name
```

If you ***know*** that every `name` ***always*** has at least one record in ***both*** tables, you don't need the `ISNULL()` and can use `INNER JOIN` instead.